# Obtain libAdIdAccess.a via Carthage for GoogleIDFASupport

Tags: ios, firebase, idfa

My task currently is to enable IDFA Collection for an app. For that I'm supposed to link two libraries according to this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en.

AdSupport.Framework I can find but I've no clue where to get libAdIdAccess.a from. It seems to be  part of https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleIDFASupport, but as the title already tells I can't use any pods for this project.

As we already imported firebase stuff like this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md I thought it may be part of that but it also isn't.

So I now hope to find the answer to where I can obtain this library from when not using cocoa pods but rather carthage?

Answer (score 2):

Google provides only two official ways to import that binary: via Cocoapods and by downloading zip file from their site with all that extra dependencies ~ 1gb. 
Anyway, you can find in Cocoapods logs (via --verbose command) the url with the only file you needed. Here is the link to git repository with the dependency https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/1/c/4/GoogleIDFASupport

You may manually import that binary to your project, or make a private git and provide it to your carthfile via `git [git address] [sha commit]`